# How to set up data binding for group radio button in Silverlight?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, data-binding, silverlight-5.0

Sliverlight provides radio button with GroupName to group radiobutton together with only one option from mutiple choice. It's like:

```
<RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 1"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 2"></RadioButton>
<RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 3"></RadioButton>
```

then in VM, I have only one property for this option,say it's MyChoice

```
public int MyChoice {get; set;}
```

then how to setup data binding for this case between UI and VM?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Used a converter to convert bools to an int:

On Xaml, asssuming options map to 1,2,3 on your MyChoice property:

```
    <RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 1"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyChoice, Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonToIntConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter=1}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 2"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyChoice, Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonToIntConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter=2}"/>
    <RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 3"
                 IsChecked="{Binding Path=MyChoice, Converter={StaticResource RadioButtonToIntConverter}, 
        ConverterParameter=3}"/>
```

In the converter, noting that I did not add any cast protection:

```
public class RadioButtonToIntConverter:IValueConverter 
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var para = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        var myChoice = System.Convert.ToInt32(value);
        return para == myChoice;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var para = System.Convert.ToInt32(parameter);
        var isChecked = System.Convert.ToBoolean(value);
        return isChecked ? para : Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

Also you'd better to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in you ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you will have to create three properties of type bool and bind to IsChecked property of RadioButton

```
<StackPanel>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 1" IsChecked="{Binding MyChoice1}"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 2" IsChecked="{Binding MyChoice2}"></RadioButton>
        <RadioButton GroupName="Option" Content="Option 3" IsChecked="{Binding MyChoice3}"></RadioButton>
    </StackPanel>
```

> ViewModel

```
        public class ViewModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        bool myChoice1;

        public bool MyChoice1
        {
            get { return myChoice1; }
            set { 
                myChoice1 = value;
                Notify("MyChoice1");
            }
        }
        bool myChoice2;

        public bool MyChoice2
        {
            get { return myChoice2; }
            set
            {
                myChoice2 = value;
                Notify("MyChoice2");
            }
        }
        bool myChoice3;

        public bool MyChoice3
        {
            get { return myChoice3; }
            set
            {
                myChoice3 = value;
                Notify("MyChoice3");
            }
        }

        public void Notify(string propName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));

        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```